# Windows Explorer alternative that can sort by anything without separating files and folders

Tags: windows, file-management

In Windows Explorer, sorting by anything (e.g. name, date modified, etc.) separates files and folders into two groups. Natively, [it's](https://superuser.com/questions/416059/show-files-and-folders-sorted-by-name-not-folders-first-then-files) [impossible](https://superuser.com/questions/183389/windows-explorer-sort-by-date-modified) to prevent that.

I'm looking for some alternative that can sort without making this separation.

The alternative should **preferably be something that can integrate into the native Windows Explorer** (because I already have other software (like [QTTabBar](http://qttabbar.wikidot.com/)) that's "integrated" into the native Windows Explorer), like some context menu utility.
However, an entire Windows Explorer alternative that can do that is also acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

## Double Commander

> [Double Commander](https://doublecmd.sourceforge.io/) is a free cross platform open source file
> manager with two panels side by side. It is inspired by Total
> Commander and features some new ideas.

You can use only one panel if you want, just click on the middle bar and drag it to the right (completely or to the % you want). Just make sure the tab at the left is selected by clicking on it (the path will be in blue). Just remember the second panel is on the right side. You also have an Horizontal Panels Mode.

In *configuration/Options/Files views* you have the possibility to sort by anything without separating files and folders. Click Apply, than OK. Maybe you will have to restart Double Commander. The configuration will be kept.

[image: Double Commander]

You can add tabs like (like QTTabBar).

There are a lot of features : Rename tool, extract files, checksum, compare files by content, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use [Files](https://files.community/).

Here you can set that option:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is a whole Explorer replacement, but Directory Opus from [GPSoft](https://www.gpsoft.com.au/) can do this.  The folder sort settings can be set to keep folders separate, or mixed together (see below).

I've been using Directory Opus for years, and can recommend it as an essential utility for Windows.

[image: Snip of folder settings dialog showing sorting options]